# Django 1.4.1 error reporting don't send me an email

Tags: django, django-1.4

This question is probably a duplicated question and sorry about that.

I'm using `Django 1.4.1` and on production server I set `DEBUG` to `False`.
Sometimes users get an Exception and server shows `500.html` template but don't send an email configured in `ADMINS` section of `settings.py`.

In application sending email is properly configured because under registration process I can receive Welcome Email.

Fragment of my `settings.py`:

```python
DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    ('example', 'example@example.com'), # this changed but my email is correct
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your server setup? the error might be happening before you hit the application server, meaning that django doesn't get the opportunity to send the mail

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Problem (Exception) is raised deep in business logic (inside VIEW function) and Django corretly serves 500.html template

Comment: I know it's a dumb question but you'd be surprised. Did you check your spam folder ?

Comment: Have you added mail settings, ie the smtp server to use and the settings for that?

Comment: in my question: `In application sending email is properly configured because under registration process I can receive Welcome Email.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django not sending emails to admins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414130/django-not-sending-emails-to-admins)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you set SERVER_EMAIL in settings. Thats the from address used to send out error mails. Default is root@localhost which might be getting blocked at SMTP. Might want to set it the same as DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL

Answer (score 10):

This has been driving me mad for a while now. JUST figured it out:

```
ADMINS = (
    ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
                                         *****
)
```

That comma at the end was all I forgot and it was enough to break it. Thought I'd share it so some other poor idiot like me can save himself some precious hair that he might otherwise have pulled out...