# django runserver show error stacktrace when DEBUG=False

Tags: django

I am getting 500 error when DEBUG is set to False, and I am unable to get any error emails too, tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414130/django-not-sending-emails-to-admins) but no success.

I have also tried option `--traceback` but all I am getting from the console is:

```
[22/Mar/2014 22:19:58] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 2263
```

Comment: What do you get with `DEBUG=True`?

Comment: everything working fine when DEBUG=True

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was I have logging defined, which overridden the [default logging config](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py)

Simply adding this to my logging config will show the error in console.

```
      'django.request': {
          'handlers': ['console'],
          'level': 'ERROR',
          'propagate': True,
      },
```